# Do I store all of the ClaimedIdentifier?

Tags: openid, dotnetopenauth

I am using dotnetopenauth and I am wondering what should I be storing from claimedIdentifier. I thought it would be just an id but it seems to have a url too.

When I do something like

```
Identifier claimedIdentifier = openIdRelayingParty.ClaimedIdentifier;
```

I get

//yahoo

```
https://me.yahoo.com/a/2RCv_bQ7341PA3v4irf5tzu_9K_fF1414afa414
```

// google

```
https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id?id=AItOawmMvmoomT7lOO5jwEaAd1414dfafaf241VUI
```

So do I store this whole thing or just the long string? If I should store the the long string then how to I extract it out? It seems like each provider formatting is a bit different.

Comment: I'm not familiar with DotNetOpenAuth, but what do you mean by "long string" vs. "id" vs. "url"? In OpenID, the identifier *is* a URL (whose format is specific to each provider)

Comment: ya I guess I mean Id. I just called it a long string the id part because yahoo does not actually label it as a id in their url.So I should be storing the entire url?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should store the entire URL, *including the fragment* part.  The fragment part is the #fragment at the end of some URLs.  For example, I think every Yahoo ClaimedIdentifier actually includes a fragment like this:

https://me.yahoo.com/a/2RCv_bQ7341PA3v4irf5tzu_9K_fF1414afa414#aHd88

It is vitally important that the *entire* ClaimedIdentifier be stored, and later used to identify the same person.  Also, be sure your identity check is [case sensitive](http://blog.nerdbank.net/2008/07/case-for-case-sensitive-openid-url.html).  Do *not* use the `System.Uri.Equals` method to verify that two ClaimedIds are equivalent.  It would return `true` in cases where only the #fragment is different, which is *not correct*.  You should use `Identifier.Equals` or the simple `String.Equals(string, string, StringComparison.Ordinal)` method.

Or if you're looking up the user from  your users table in a database, be certain that your users table is configured to be case sensitive for the ClaimedId column.

Comment: How about if your using a orm mapper like nhibernate(it generates the database for me). I am not quite sure how to tell it to do a case sensitive check. I would figure I would just take what I get and do a something like where(u => u.OpenId == ClaimedIdentifer).FirstOrDefault()

Comment: That totally depends on the ORM you're using and what its rules are.  A good ORM will translate your lambda query that you gave in your example to a SQL query.  That makes it up to the SQL engine to determine whether it should be case sensitive, which of course it will do or not do depending on the schema that the ORM originally used when it created the db.  You'll have to look up in the ORM documentation to find out how to ensure a column is case sensitive.  Testing it should be easy.  Write some code that shouldn't match but is different only in capitalization and see if it works.